# Update command in sql having issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below details in the table

```
GEMS@TEST1>select BUILTIN_ARGUMENTS from FND_FORM_CUSTOM_ACTIONS WHERE (RULE_ID = 2243);

BUILTIN_ARGUMENTS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
='http://prod.client.com:3001/ords/f?p=1:2:::NO::P_ORDER_HEADER_ID,P_SESSION
_ID:'||${item.ORDER.HEADER_ID.VALUE}||','||${ps.db_session_id.value}
```

For a need ,I have to update this `"prod.client.com:3001"` as

```
"test1-scan.client.com"
```

When I am executing below getting error

```
GEMS@TEST1>update FND_FORM_CUSTOM_ACTIONS set = '='http://test1-scan.client.com/ords/f?p=1:2:::NO::P_ORDER_HEADER_ID,P_SESSION
_ID:'||${item.ORDER.HEADER_ID.VALUE}||','||${ps.db_session_id.value}' WHERE (RULE_ID = 2243);
SP2-0552: Bind variable "NO" not declared.    

GEMS@TEST1>
```

I know I might have to use escape character or declare the variable but not getting clue as I am not very good in coding .

Comment: You got to format the question, its hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `REPLACE` in this case is better.

```
UPDATE fnd_form_custom_actions
SET    builtin_arguments = REPLACE (builtin_arguments, 'prod.client.com:3001',
                                  'test1-scan.client.com')
WHERE   rule_id = 2243 ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it solved the purpose . Thanks once again for prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

You have obvious typos in your statement:

```
set = '='http://test1-scan.client.com/ords/f?p=1:2:::NO  [.......]
```

set **what** = .....?

Then: what is with the second equal sign, in single quotes? (OR... I see - did you mean single quotes within the assigned string? You must enter TWO single quotes to represent one single quote in a string!)

Then: since the second equal sign consumes the single quotes, what follows AFTER it is not quoted. So `:NO` is seen as a bind variable. Correct the syntax and Oracle won't ask you about any bind variables.

With that fixed, look at Kaushik's answer for a better approach altogether.